# I have jekyll 3.1.2 installed but my system is still using jekyll 3.0.3

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

I am trying to get my system to use gem Jekyll 3.1.2 when I run the command

> $ jekyll new .

As you can see from the below list of Gem files I have both versions of jekyll 3.1.2 and 3.0.3 installed.

```
$ gem list jekyll                                                                                         

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

jekyll (3.1.2, 3.0.3)
jekyll-coffeescript (1.0.1)
jekyll-feed (0.4.0)
jekyll-gist (1.4.0)
jekyll-github-metadata (1.9.0)
jekyll-mentions (1.1.2)
jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
jekyll-redirect-from (0.10.0)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.4.0, 1.3.0)
jekyll-seo-tag (1.3.2)
jekyll-sitemap (0.10.0)
jekyll-textile-converter (0.1.0)
jekyll-watch (1.3.1)
```

It seems however that the version that is being used is 3.0.3:

```
$ jekyll -v
jekyll 3.0.3
```

I tried to manually uninstall jekyll 3.0.3 but I get the following warning:

```
You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    jekyll-3.0.3

github-pages-66 depends on jekyll (= 3.0.3)
jekyll-feed-0.4.0 depends on jekyll (< 3.1.0, >= 2.4.0, development)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [yN]
```

I do use Github pages, so removing this version will break the Github pages gem....

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install [Bundler](http://bundler.io/), if you don't have it installed yet. Run `gem install bundler`
2. Create a folder to your Jekyll project (if you haven't done it yet)
3. Create a `Gemfile` inside this folder with the following content:

   ```
   source "https://rubygems.org"

   gem 'jekyll', '3.1.2'
   ```
4. On your terminal, navigate to your project's folder by `cd/path/to/project`
5. Run `bundle install`
6. Run `bundle exec jekyll new . --force`

Done!

*Note: `--force` will create a new jekyll even if the current folder is not empty*

Comment: Super, this worked. Just as a FYI to anyone else following your above steps... quickest way to create a Gemfile (if one has Bundler installed) is to navigate to the project folder and type `$bundle init`